# Unexpected SocketTimeoutException on Android 3 tablet

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, socket-timeout-exception

I've got an application which reads data from an url using

```
final URL url = new URL("http", ip, 80, path);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + StringUtils.toBase64(user + ":" + pass));
conn.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
conn.setReadTimeout(timeout);
while (true) {
  readLineAndOutputOk();
}
```

with a timeout of 60000. The source returns data every 15 seconds, so there should be no timeout. But 2:19 after opening the url connection a **java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out** is thrown. I tested this with a **Huawai Mediapad 7**. Same code works well on some Android 2 devices, phones and tablets.

Anybody hit this problem already or is this device specific?

edit: (clarification that data is received and no real timeout is the cause.)
I have logged that **data is received every 15s**. There is no pause, no broken connection.
The exception is thrown e.g. 4s after the last data was received.

Comment: SocketException is never unexpected. Network can be unavailable for device, for example because it has weaker antenna.

Comment: @lechlukasz: I know a SocketException can occur, but a "Connection timeout" should only be thrown if there has been no data for the specified time (i.e. 60s). If I can definitely see data arriving 4s before the exception in thrown (value differs)  i do NOT expect a timeout.

Comment: more puzzling: it's not a SocketTimeoutException (which I expected), but a SocketException with a timeout message. Is this some android feature to prevent long running connections?